# Liquibase on multiple databases

Tags: maven, liquibase

I have already implemented Liquibase with Maven. We are currently using a single database (db2) but now we need to add a new database to the application which will have different objects.

I've seen that i can define a new profile in maven but i couldn't find out how to differentiate which objects is being created on which database.

Is there a solution to this? Can I support 2 different databases with different objects using liquibase?

Comment: How you configure `liquibase`? `cdi`, `spring`, etc. Or you just execute `mvn` to proccess the migrations?

Comment: @AVolpe: we are using maven in order to process the db changes.

Answer (score 5):

As you can see in the [documentation](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/maven/), you can use two different executions, like this:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
  <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.5</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>process-resources</phase>
      <configuration>
        <changeLogFile>PATH_TO_CHANGELOG_1</changeLogFile>
        ... connection properties  ...
      </configuration>
      <goals>
        <goal>update</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
   <execution>
      <phase>process-resources</phase>
      <configuration>
        <changeLogFile>PATH_TO_CHANGELOG_2</changeLogFile>
        ... connection properties  ...
      </configuration>
      <goals>
        <goal>update</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

The only problem with this approach is that you need two different `changelog.xml` files, one per database.

Also, you can have [preconditions](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/preconditions.html) in your changelog file to choose between what *changeset* will be processed by each database.

For example:

```
<changeSet id="1" author="bob">
    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
         <dbms type="oracle" />
    </preConditions>
    <comment>Comments should go after preCondition. If they are before then liquibase usually gives error.</comment>
    <dropTable tableName="oldtable"/>
</changeSet>
```

The `onFail="MARK_RAN"` makes Liquibase skip the changeset but marks it as run, so the next time it will not try again. See the `customPrecondition` tag in the [documentation](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/preconditions.html)  for more complex preconditions.

Comment: How to provide `PATH_TO_CHANGELOG_1` as path inside a maven artifact which is already added as a dependency?

Comment: Make sure that `version` is provided along with `artifactId`. For some reason, it doesn't inherit from parent pom.

Comment: Since with this approach the command `mvn liquibase:update`doesn't work , how can I make rollbacks?

Answer (score 4):

You may want to have 2 separate changelogs to manage the two databases, even if they are both used by the same application.

Answer (score 2):

As Arturo says you can have 2 or more execution-nodes, but you must give every execution-node a seperate id.

```
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.5</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>db1-update</id>
                            <phase>process-resources</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/org/liquibase/db1.xml</changeLogFile>
                                <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
                                <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost/db1</url>
                                <username>..</username>
                                <password>..</password>
                            </configuration>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>update</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>db2-update</id>
                            <phase>process-resources</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/org/liquibase/db2.xml</changeLogFile>
                                <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
                                <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost/db2</url>
                                <username>...</username>
                                <password>...</password>
                            </configuration>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>update</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>db3-update</id>
                            <phase>process-resources</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/org/liquibase/db3.xml</changeLogFile>
                                <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
                                <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost/db3</url>
                                <username>...</username>
                                <password>...</password>
                            </configuration>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>update</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Preconditions inside changeset or changelog and give conditions according to the database,

```
<preConditions  onFail="WARN">
    <dbms  type="oracle"  />
    <runningAs  username="SYSTEM"/>
</preConditions>
```

Like this, you can use precondition tag inside changeset and give conditions according to each database.

Use this [link](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/advanced/preconditions.html) for additions documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Old question but I still answer cause I have the same requirement today, and I am opting for another solution.

I would recommend, if you can, as proposed already in the answers to use seperate changelogs.

But if you want to keep the changelogs unified, as I need for my specific case, I would use labels instead of preconditions to filter changesets to be executed.

```
<changeSet id="0001:1" author="oz" labels="clickhouse">
    <sql>...SOMESQL...</sql>
</changeSet>

<changeSet id="0001:2" author="oz" labels="mongodb">
    <ext:createCollection collectionName="myCollection">
         ...SOMEJSON....
    </ext:createCollection>
</changeSet>
```

This will prevent poluting the databasechangelog of the two databases with the executions of the changesets of the other database.
This will cause problems(for the current release at least 4.6.1) for any liquibase operation using tags, such as rollbackToTag or updateToTag.