# Liquibase detects h2 as database even when h2 runs in MySQL mode [Spring boot]

Tags: spring, spring-boot, integration-testing, h2, liquibase

I am trying to run the tests of my Spring Boot application using liquibase and h2 (in mysql mode). The Liquibase changelogs are MySQL specific so I was thinking that testing with liquibase enabled and h2 in MySQL mode would do the trick.

Problem is that Liquibase is not detecting the database as MySQL but as H2. So when performing migration it uses wrong data types e.g. CLOB instead of TEXT which later causes the hibernate validator to fail.

I need to know if there is any way to force liquibase to use MySQL specific migrations regardless of the database the application is actually connecting to. Not sure how liquibase figures out the database but I'm guessing using driver name or db url maybe?

If anyone has any alternative solutions, ideas please do suggest!

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: test   
 datasource:
   url: jdbc:h2:mem:ebdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;MODE=MySQL
   username: sa
   password:
   driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
 jpa:
   database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
   database: MYSQL
   hibernate:
      ddl-auto: validate
liquibase:
  change-log: classpath:liquibase/liquibase-changeLog.xml
  enabled: true
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question correctly, you may add the `dbms="mysql` or `dbms="h2"` attribute to your `changeSet` as such:

`<changeSet id="theId" author="theAuthor" dbms="mysql">`

This way, `liquibase` will execute this `changeSet` only if you're connected to `mysql` database.

**Or** you can add `dbms`check in `preConditions`:

```
<preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
    <dbms type="h2"/>
</preConditions>
```

Comment: No not exactly. As liquibase is detecting H2 it's creating columns based on H2 data types. This happens even in MySQL mode. What I need is to get liquibase to detect and use MySQL migration commands even when connected to H2.

Comment: @TahmidEkram, Maybe this question will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25364023/liquibase-on-multiple-databases